# React JS output for navbar not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am copying the code from youtube but my output is not showing. I was trying to work with bootstrap and react js to make navbar.
But the youtube guy was making navbar using HTML and Bootstrap.
The classes are same but still I can only see one small container with 100% of dark color.
youtube guy code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVJWu9_NJes&list=PLwGdqUZWnOp2f1JwXA3k47UteMxaIw6j4&index=7&t=810s TIME 14:43

```
import React from "react";
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div className="container">
        <a href="" className="navbar-brand">
          Maryam Inc.
        </a>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          data-toggler="collapse"
          data-target="#navbaraid"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbaraid">
          <ul className="navbar-nav text-center ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                About
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Contact;
```

App file: (I'm not attaching other files mentioned in App because theyre working fine)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Home from "./Home";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Services from "./Services";
import About from "./About";

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <About />
      <h1 id="name" style={{ color: "blue" }}>
        Maryam
      </h1>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path="/Services" component={Services} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Index js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import index from "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "./Contact";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: You need to use React-Bootstrap. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: still not working. these are my dependencies        "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-digital-clock": "^0.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },

Answer (score 1):

You just have to link `bootstrap` and `jquery` cdn links in your `index.html` file. The links mentioned in the video, I have pasted in the demo below.

check out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sara-skfsq?file=/public/index.html)

p.s: `react-bootstrap` is not necessarily required.